# How to convert a Java console application to a Full Stack web application using Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, system-design

So the project I want to convert is at https://github.com/zhongjis/keyword_search_engine_xlsm.

This program intends to build a search engine based on the user input files (xlsm). It extracts content from an XLSM (excel) file first and stores them to the DB. while building up the database, the program will also calculate some special numbers such as td-idf which will be used later for result ranking.

#### Current technology used:

- Gradle
- Java 13
- MongoDB

#### What I am trying to do?

- convert this console application to a full-stack web application that uses Spring Framework. which means that I want to add a GUI.
- I am trying to keep as much original code as possible during this transition. For me, it is ok to modify them to fit the MVC design.
- In one sentence, **I want to make my current application runs on the Spring framework. it is OK only to have console output**.

#### What are my questions?

- even though I did a lot of research on Spring Framework (especially Spring boot). But I am still struggles with what should I do first in order to implement the framework. **I would like some suggestions on how to start (or what should I change on my original project)**. All I learned from the internet is adding various dependencies to build.gradle. But I still have no idea what to do next. **Should I start a new Web Application from scratch or try to convert the current one**?

#### Thank you

- I tried my best to fill in details. However, this post might still be vague or confusing on some parts and need some clarification. Please feel free to let me know and I am more than willing to do that :)

Comment: It's a fine question, but not a good question for StackOverflow. It's broad, opinion-based, and better suited to any online tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you want to create a Web Application.

The easiest way to get started is to use Spring Boot, which is the 'opinionated' version of Spring, meaning that it uses smart defaults. You should start by using the Initializer to generate your project: https://start.spring.io/. Keep generating and testing until you get what you want.

The simplest method is to build an executable JAR, which will contain your web server and can be run anywhere you have Java. This is the default setting on Initializer site above. My advice: Accept Spring Boot defaults until you know what you're doing.

GUI:
The simplest method is to use Thymeleaf templates to display your HTML.

Controller:
Learn how to write a basic controller to return a Thymeleaf template. The simplest way to begin is with standard HTML posting to your controller.

Docs
A great strength of Spring is the ample documentation.
See: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/
and: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you start with Spring Initializr to bootstrap a fully working Spring Boot application.  Alternatively, you can use JHipster(https://www.jhipster.tech/) which will create a Spring Boot app AND a front-end for you which you may prefer.

**Create a base application**

https://start.spring.io/

Select the dependencies you need such a MongoDB:

[image: Dependencies]

**Build out basic components**

So the basic flow in a Spring Boot App is Controller -> Service layer -> Repository.

The Controller will allow you to create REST endpoints annotated with `@RestController`:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Then put your business logic from your util package into a service class annotated with `@Service`.
https://medium.com/stackavenue/why-to-use-service-layer-in-spring-mvc-5f4fc52643c0

You will autowire your Service layer into the Controller using a `@Autowired` annotation.

Then create a Spring Repository for database operations:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Then `@Autowire` your Repository into your Service layer.

In summary, the whole flow is your front-end(Angular, ReactJS etc.) makes a HTTP call to your Spring App which is handled by the Controller which calls the service layer which calls the Repository to perform database operations.

**Building a Front-end**

You can use Angular for this.  A lot of front-end devs prefer React but for a new user, Angular is a more holistic framework in my opinion. https://cli.angular.io/

Install npm(https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm)

Then do the following to get a fully functional Angular app up and running:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-dream-app
cd my-dream-app
ng serve
```

Then you can use the Angular `HttpClient` to make a call to your Spring Boot service:  https://angular.io/guide/http

This repo is a couple years old but it contains a full-stack Angular/Spring Boot app that you can check out for reference:  https://github.com/anataliocs/Exercise-files-full-stack-app-angular-spring-boot.

You could use Thymeleaf as well(https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) but most modern Full-stack web apps use a separate front-end app such as Angular, React(https://reactjs.org/), Vue.js(https://vuejs.org/) etc.

**JHipster**

Jhipster will do all this and also hook up a fully working front-end for you.  https://www.jhipster.tech/

**Courses**

I also have full courses on building full-stack apps on LinkedIn learning, but full disclosure, it's not a free service but there is a 30 day trial.

- [Full-stack app with Angular and Spring Boot](https://linkedin-learning.pxf.io/building-a-full-stack-app-with-angular-2-plus-and-spring-boot)
- [Full-stack app with
  JHipster](https://linkedin-learning.pxf.io/jhipster-build-and-deploy-spring-boot-microservices)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest the same as KevinB use SpringBoot/Thymeleaf for easy MVC style application to minimize using too many technology stack.

But before you jump into action remember any migration of project/application into new framework or architecture first needs breaking down the components (source as well as target and then mapping them).

The github project utilizes MONGODB which you would not need to re setup.

You can do the migration in 2 ways, based on functionality i.e build all of backend and front for a functionality at a time

or develop mock rest end points first and then do the UI making call to service end points in spring boot.